# SpringBoot Multiple DataSource - Fails only in External Tomcat Container

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

SpringBoot Multiple DataSource - Fails in External Tomcat Container

We are creating the two different datasource (microsoft sqlserver) with springboot. This works properly inside eclipse Luna tomcat container.
when we tried deploying the war file in external tomcat(8.0.x) container, fails with below exception.

Please let us know are we missing any configuration as it works properly inside eclipse

### Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getPrimaryBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:237)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.hasSingleAutowireCandidate(OnBeanCondition.java:230)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:102)
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:436)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:127)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:677)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
```

### First Datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.adapter.repository.first",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EntityScan("com.example.adapter.domain.first")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class FirstDataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource())
            .packages("com.example.adapter.domain.first")
            .persistenceUnit("first")
            .build()
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory)
    }
}
```

### Second DataSource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.adapter.repository.second",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager")
@EntityScan("com.example.adapter.domain.second")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SecondDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.second")
    public DataSource secondDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
        return builder
            .dataSource(secondDataSource())
            .packages("com.example.adapter.domain.second")
            .persistenceUnit("secondPersistenceUnit")
            .build()
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory)
    }
}
```

### Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXX:1433;databaseName=XXXXX
spring.datasource.username: XXXXXX
spring.datasource.password: XXXXXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

datasource.second.url: jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXXX:1433;databaseName=XXXXXX
datasource.second.username: XXXXXX
datasource.second.password: XXXXXX
datasource.second.driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql: false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

### MainApplication:

```
@EnableCaching
@CompileStatic
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=[MultipartAutoConfiguration.class])
class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }

    static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args)
    }

}
```

### build.xml (Gradle Build changes - external war deployment)

```
apply plugin: 'war'

providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed by removing the multiple usage of @EnableAutoConfiguration in the application.
We noticed @EnableAutoConfiguration has been used in Swaggerconfig file along with MainApplication.java and we removed in Swaggerconfig file.

Now application is working proper in local and external tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough the solution works proper in local and external tomcat in Windows OS but fails in Linux environment.

Linux behaviour:

a) Tomcat is NOT allowing the custom bean name for TransactionManager and EntityManagerFactory for @Primary datasource like firstTransactionManager and firstEntityManagerFactory, so forced to use the bean name as transactionManager and entityManagerFactory. [Same works in Windows OS with external tomcat container]
b) After changing the bean name to TransactionManager and EntityManagerFactory, application is deployed in Linux Tomcat without any fail but always execute the query in primary datasource and getting the error as table not found, where in the table is part of second data source

Note:- Tomcat Version is 8.0.29 and JDK Version is 1.8.31, which is same both in Windows and Linux.

Please let us know are we missing any configuration as it works properly in Windows Tomcat.